# How get Parent child div valule

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

want to get `<span class="price">Rs.5,190.00</span>` using jquery, below is html

```
<div id="checkout-review" class="onepagecheckout_block">
      <div class="op_block_title"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Review YourOrder</div>
      <div id="checkout-review-load" class="" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
         <div id="checkout-review-table-wrapper">
           <tr class="first">
              <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="2">Subtotal</td>
              <td style="" class="a-right last"><span class="price">Rs.5,190.00</span></td>
           </tr>
         </div>
      <div>
```

Comment: paste your html .

Comment: <tr class="first">
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="2">
        Subtotal    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right last">
        <span class="price">Rs. 5,190.00</span>    </td>
</tr>

Comment: <div id="checkout-review" class="onepagecheckout_block">
<div class="op_block_title"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Review YourOrder</div>
<div id="checkout-review-load" class="" style="width: auto; height: auto;"><div id="checkout-review-table-wrapper">
<tr class="first">
<td style="" class="a-right" colspan="2">
Subtotal</td>
<td style="" class="a-right last">
<span class="price">Rs. 5,190.00</span></td>
</tr>
</div>
<div>

Comment: now what you want to get ?

Comment: <span class="price">Rs. 5,190.00</span> this one

Comment: try this `jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price').text();`  this code will give you `Rs. 5,190.00` and if you want only price then you use this- `var price = jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price').text(); price = price.replace( /^\D+/g, '')`

Comment: or if you want whole span tag like this `<span class="price">Rs. 5,190.00</span>` then just simply use`jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price')`

Comment: its show all product price in cart i want just sub total price

Comment: did you get what you wanted from my answer ?

Comment: not 100%  but helpfull thanks

Comment: let me know please what your 100% is , I will try my best to help you.

Comment: i just want subtotal price currently it shows also grand total and product prices too

Comment: can you paste what you have tried ?

Comment: <tr class="first">
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="2">
        Subtotal    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right last">
        <span class="price">Rs. 5,190.00</span>    </td>

Comment: ok can you give it a try `jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper tr.first').find('span.price')`

Comment: i think i need to add class because now to results are cining in need to add class in subtotal htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try -

> to get this `<span class="price">Rs.5,190.00</span>`

use `jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price');`

> to get this `Rs. 5,190.00`

use `jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price').text();`

> to get price only like this `5,190.00`

use `var price = jQuery('#checkout-review-table-wrapper').find('span.price').text();

price = price.replace( /^\D+/g, '');`